# Strange compilation error: compiler bug or my own?

Tags: c++, gcc, eigen3

I have header-only library, and I'm getting the strangest compilation error. The problem in proceeding is that I'm not getting this error in a representative minimal example, and not on all compilers (on macOS everything compiles and runs like a charm). I am not sure if I should be worried about something in my code, or if it is an upstream bug. Regardless, I'm not sure how to work around this.

I'm getting the following compiler error:

```
In file included from /home/tdegeus/opt/include/eigen3/Eigen/SparseCore:59:0,
                 from /home/tdegeus/opt/include/eigen3/Eigen/Sparse:26,
                 from /home/tdegeus/opt/include/eigen3/Eigen/Eigen:2,
                 from /home/tdegeus/prog/src/GooseFEM/docs/examples/Statics/Periodic/LinearElasticity/main.cpp:1:
/home/tdegeus/opt/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/SparseCore/SparseSelfAdjointView.h: In function ‘void Eigen::internal::permute_symm_to_symm(const MatrixType&, Eigen::SparseMatrix<typename MatrixType::Scalar, DestOrder, typename MatrixType::StorageIndex>&, const typename MatrixType::StorageIndex*) [with int SrcMode = 1; int DstMode = 2; MatrixType = Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>; int DestOrder = 0]’:
/home/tdegeus/opt/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/SparseCore/SparseSelfAdjointView.h:517:6: internal compiler error: in predicate_mem_writes, at tree-if-conv.c:2252
 void permute_symm_to_symm(const MatrixType& mat, SparseMatrix<typename MatrixType::Scalar,DstOrder,typename MatrixType::StorageIndex>& _dest, const typename MatrixType::StorageIndex* perm)
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
0xb3530b predicate_mem_writes
    /ssoft/spack/paien/spack.v2/var/spack/stage/gcc-7.3.0-drb5cfgzldhzbrs6lyzk7xdqqcixbxhb/gcc-7.3.0/gcc/tree-if-conv.c:2252
0xb3530b combine_blocks
    /ssoft/spack/paien/spack.v2/var/spack/stage/gcc-7.3.0-drb5cfgzldhzbrs6lyzk7xdqqcixbxhb/gcc-7.3.0/gcc/tree-if-conv.c:2377
0xb359bb tree_if_conversion(loop*)
    /ssoft/spack/paien/spack.v2/var/spack/stage/gcc-7.3.0-drb5cfgzldhzbrs6lyzk7xdqqcixbxhb/gcc-7.3.0/gcc/tree-if-conv.c:2883
0xb3663b execute
    /ssoft/spack/paien/spack.v2/var/spack/stage/gcc-7.3.0-drb5cfgzldhzbrs6lyzk7xdqqcixbxhb/gcc-7.3.0/gcc/tree-if-conv.c:2961
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
Please include the complete backtrace with any bug report.
See <https://gcc.gnu.org/bugs/> for instructions.
```

Which disappears if I comment this line (obviously breaking functionality):

```cpp
m_solver.compute(m_ACuu);
```

Note that:

```cpp
Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> m_ACuu;
Eigen::SimplicialLDLT<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>> m_solver;
```

I tried a minimal example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <Eigen/Sparse>
#include <Eigen/SparseCholesky>

int main()
{
  size_t N = 11;

  // allocate system
  Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> A(N,N);
  Eigen::VectorXd f(N);

  // set force
  f         *= 0.0;
  f((N-1)/2) = 1.0;

  // construct list of Triplets (row,col,data) that from the matrix "A"
  std::vector<Eigen::Triplet<double>> Atr;
  // - first equation
  Atr.push_back(Eigen::Triplet<double>(0,0,+2.0));
  Atr.push_back(Eigen::Triplet<double>(0,1,-1.0));
  // - body
  for ( size_t i=1; i<N-1; ++i ) {
    Atr.push_back(Eigen::Triplet<double>(i,i-1,-1.0));
    Atr.push_back(Eigen::Triplet<double>(i,i  ,+2.0));
    Atr.push_back(Eigen::Triplet<double>(i,i+1,-1.0));
  }
  // - last equation
  Atr.push_back(Eigen::Triplet<double>(N-1,N-2,-1.0));
  Atr.push_back(Eigen::Triplet<double>(N-1,N-1,+2.0));

  // build matrix from Triplets
  A.setFromTriplets(Atr.begin(),Atr.end());

  // solve the linear system
  // - define solver (according to type above)
  Eigen::SimplicialLDLT<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>> solver;
  // - analyze the system, and factorize (one could solve different right-hand-sides)
  // solver.analyzePattern(A);
  solver.factorize(A);
  // - solve "A * x = f"
  Eigen::VectorXd u = solver.solve(f);

  // print to screen
  std::cout << A << std::endl;
  std::cout << u << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Compiled on the same system with the same libraries and with similar options:

```sh
g++ -march=native -O3 test.cpp
```

**But this compiles and runs like a charm!?**

Note that I've tried several Eigen versions, including 3.3.90.

**Edit**

Also note that this problem occurs with

```sh
g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 7.3.0
```

But is gone for

```sh
g++ (GCC) 6.4.0
```

Comment: The phrases "internal compiler error" and "Please submit a full bug report" make it pretty clear that you've encountered a compiler bug. If you're not using the latest compiler, it may have been fixed in a newer release.

Comment: [Based on this](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=News:Eigen_3.3.7_released!) it is known problem. What is your compiler version?

Comment: Compiles cleanly for me with GCC 7.3 and Eigen 3.3.4: https://godbolt.org/z/-cF1CO

Comment: @MarekR I'm using GCC 7.3.0 (see edit). Also note that I'm using the master of https://github.com/eigenteam/eigen-git-mirror (it says version 3.3.90 in `Core/util/Macros.h`, although that does not correspond a version listed on the site of Eigen)

Comment: @P.W As listed, I'm having difficulty constructing an example in which the compiler error shows up. It occurs in my library, but not in the minimal example. So this makes it very difficult to find.

Comment: @MarekR Also not that I did switch on optimisation. The site you listed seems to imply that the problem on occurs without optimisation.

Comment: If I were you I would try to find issue description in Eigen. Note in release notes is very similar, so finding this issue analysis can give you an extra hints or possible workarounds.

Comment: @MarekR Thanks I will. In the mean time it seems that the problem disappears for gcc 6.4.0

Comment: ICEs are usually hard to track down. Sometimes removing or adding seemingly unrelated lines can make the problem disappear. Do as @molbdnilo and submit a bug report (following the instructions). Often it is helpful to split your code into smaller compilation units (this also can speed up re-compilation times).